# Path request submitted through Postman issues 404 response

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

**Issue Details**

I am using Laravel 8. There is a patch route. I am trying to submit the patch request through postman. Due to some reasons it shows 404 response.

Please let me know if you need more information.

**Laravel Route**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\User\Role\RoleApiController;

Route::patch("update-role/{role_id}", [
    RoleApiController::class, 
    "Update"
])->name("UpdateRoleApi");
```

**Route Proof in console**

[image]

**Controller**

```
class RoleApiController extends Controller {
        
    public function Update(UpdateRoleRequest $request, $role_id) {
        return \Response::json([], 200);
    }
}
```

**Request**

```
class UpdateRoleRequest extends FormRequest {
    
    public function wantsJson() {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            "role_id" => "required",
            "role" => "required"
        ];
    }
}
```

**Postman request**

[image]

**PostMan Patch Request Logs**

```
PATCH http://192.168.1.3:1234/My/learning/1/backend/Laravel/practise1/public/api/v1/update-role?api_token=token/role_id: {
  "Network": {
    "addresses": {
      "local": {
        "address": "192.168.1.3",
        "family": "IPv4",
        "port": 54995
      },
      "remote": {
        "address": "192.168.1.3",
        "family": "IPv4",
        "port": 1234
      }
    }
  },
  "Request Headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.29.2",
    "postman-token": "c277824a-093d-4324-a17c-84a033e91719",
    "host": "192.168.1.3:1234",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "content-length": "36"
  },
  "Request Body": "{\"role\": \"Test ABC A\", \"role_id\": 2}",
  "Response Headers": {
    "date": "Thu, 06 Oct 2022 07:59:23 GMT",
    "server": "Apache/2.4.53 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1n PHP/7.4.29",
    "x-powered-by": "PHP/7.4.29",
    "cache-control": "no-cache, private",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  "Response Body": "{\n    \"message\": \"\",\n    \"exception\": \"Symfony\\\\Component\\\\HttpKernel\\\\Exception\\\\NotFoundHttpException\",\n    \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\AbstractRouteCollection.php\",\n    \"line\": 43,\n    \"trace\": [\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\RouteCollection.php\",\n            \"line\": 162,\n            \"function\": \"handleMatchedRoute\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\AbstractRouteCollection\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Router.php\",\n            \"line\": 673,\n            \"function\": \"match\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\RouteCollection\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Router.php\",\n            \"line\": 662,\n            \"function\": \"findRoute\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Router\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Router.php\",\n            \"line\": 651,\n            \"function\": \"dispatchToRoute\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Router\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel.php\",\n            \"line\": 167,\n            \"function\": \"dispatch\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Router\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline.php\",\n            \"line\": 128,\n            \"function\": \"Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\{closure}\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\TransformsRequest.php\",\n            \"line\": 21,\n            \"function\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\{closure}\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php\",\n            \"line\": 31,\n            \"function\": \"handle\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\TransformsRequest\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline.php\",\n            \"line\": 167,\n            \"function\": \"handle\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\TransformsRequest.php\",\n            \"line\": 21,\n            \"function\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\{closure}\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\TrimStrings.php\",\n            \"line\": 40,\n            \"function\": \"handle\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\TransformsRequest\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline.php\",\n            \"line\": 167,\n            \"function\": \"handle\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\TrimStrings\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\ValidatePostSize.php\",\n            \"line\": 27,\n            \"function\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\{closure}\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline.php\",\n            \"line\": 167,\n            \"function\": \"handle\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\ValidatePostSize\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php\",\n            \"line\": 86,\n            \"function\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\{closure}\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline.php\",\n            \"line\": 167,\n            \"function\": \"handle\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\fruitcake\\\\laravel-cors\\\\src\\\\HandleCors.php\",\n            \"line\": 52,\n            \"function\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\{closure}\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline.php\",\n            \"line\": 167,\n            \"function\": \"handle\",\n            \"class\": \"Fruitcake\\\\Cors\\\\HandleCors\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\TrustProxies.php\",\n            \"line\": 39,\n            \"function\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\{closure}\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline.php\",\n            \"line\": 167,\n            \"function\": \"handle\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Http\\\\Middleware\\\\TrustProxies\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline.php\",\n            \"line\": 103,\n            \"function\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\{closure}\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel.php\",\n            \"line\": 142,\n            \"function\": \"then\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Pipeline\\\\Pipeline\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel.php\",\n            \"line\": 111,\n            \"function\": \"sendRequestThroughRouter\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\My\\\\learning\\\\1\\\\backend\\\\Laravel\\\\practise1\\\\public\\\\index.php\",\n            \"line\": 52,\n            \"function\": \"handle\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Http\\\\Kernel\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        }\n    ]\n}"
}
```

Comment: the postman URL should be ``update-role/{role_id}?api_token=token`` instead of ``update-role?api_token=token/role_id:``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed the wrong endpoint URL. The postman URL should be `update-role/{role_id}?api_token={token}` instead of `update-role?api_token={token}/{role_id}`.

Comment: Also did you notice role_id in request class was being passed inside json object. how do request class still make sure that the role_id is numeric and present in url? it is no more in json

Comment: @Pankaj that's called type hinting. You can read more here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: @Pankaj Use the [`exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-exists) validation rule in your `UpdateRoleRequest` to confirm the `role_id` is valid. [Here is an example of how that might work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37347678/281278).

Comment: role_id has been moved from json object to url query string, will it still work in my case?

Comment: @Pankaj, role_id needs to be passed as url path parameter and not as url query parameter.

Comment: I have already made 2 changes as suggested. `{{LaravelUrl}}/update-role/2?api_token=token` and removed role_id from request class as required field. Is that correct?

Comment: Are you trying to suggest that role_id should be both in url as well as request class? if just in url then how do I validate it in request class as it has been removed from json in request body.